# Extract e-mail addresses if they contain certain strings with Perl

Tags: string, perl, email, text-extraction

I have a big text file which is a list of e-mails (each followed by a /n).

I would like to run a perl command to make files with different lists based on whether the e-mail contains a certain string.

So far I have:

```
 perl -wne'
    while (/[\w\.\-]+@[\w\.\-]+\w+/g) {
       print if "$&\n /gmail/;
    }
 ' all_emails_extracted.csv | sort -u > output.txt
```

This should write the e-mail if it contains 'gmail' but I get syntax errors no matter how I structure the area around the {print if}

Answer (score 4):

It's normally

```
print "$&\n";
```

So if you add a statement modifier, it becomes

```
print "$&\n" if /gmail/;
```

You are missing a quote (`"`), and your `if` is misplaced.

---

A bit simpler:

```
perl -nE'say grep /gmail/, /[\w\.\-]+@[\w\.\-]+\w+/g'
```

You can even do the deduping in Perl itself.

```
perl -MList::MoreUtils=uniq -nE'say uniq grep /gmail/, /[\w\.\-]+@[\w\.\-]+\w+/g'
```

Answer (score 2):

You have significantly overcomplicated this...

```
perl -wne'print if /@.*gmail/' all_emails_extracted.csv
```

Or, even easier (but without Perl):

```
grep @.*gmail all_emails_extracted.csv
```

Comment: Both of those print the entire line instead of just the email address. They can also match the word "gmail" outside of the email address.

Answer (score 0):

The error in your code has already been pointed out, so here's another suggestion: use [Email::Address](https://metacpan.org/module/RJBS/Email-Address-1.898/lib/Email/Address.pm):

```
$ cat addresses
bob@gmail.com
bob@yahoo.com
bobette@springfield-amusement-park.com
bobbyMcBobberson@springfield-amusement-park.com
bahb@yahoo.com
bob @ yahoo.com
bob @ springfield-amusement-park.com
postmaster@hotmail.com

$ perl -MEmail::Address -lne 'for (Email::Address->parse($_)) { $bobs{$_->format}++ if $_->user =~ /bob/i } END { print for sort keys %bobs }' addresses
bob@gmail.com
bob@springfield-amusement-park.com
bob@yahoo.com
bobbyMcBobberson@springfield-amusement-park.com
bobette@springfield-amusement-park.com
```

You said you wanted to "make files with different lists"?  Email::Address can help with that, too:

```
while (<DATA>) {
  for (Email::Address->parse($_)) {
    push @{$categories{by_host}{$_->host}}, $_;
    push @{$categories{bobs}}, $_ if $_->user =~ /bob/i
  }
}
```

And then this would create a list of user names in files named after each address's hostname:

```
for my $host (keys $categories{by_host}) {
  open my $hf, '>', "hosts.$host" or die $!;
  for (@{$categories{by_host}{$host}}) {
    print {$hf} $_->user, "\n"
  }
  close $hf
}
```

So, run on that last list:

```
$ cat hosts.springfield-amusement-park.com
bobette
bobbyMcBobberson
bob

$ cat hosts.yahoo.com
bob
bahb
bob
```